# regex replacement with a increasing number

Tags: c#, regex, string, .net-3.5, replace

I would like to regex/replace the following set:

```
[something] [nothing interesting here] [boring.....]
```

by

```
%0 %1 %2
```

In other words, any expressions that is built with `[]` will become a `%` followed by an increasing number...

Is it possible to do it right away with a Regex?

Comment: What regex engine/utility are you using?

Comment: This is not possible using only regex. What implementation are you using? (Should this be Which implementation....? =) )

Comment: It would be good to know the language you're working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with regex in C#, as `Regex.Replace` can take a delegate as a parameter.

```
        Regex theRegex = new Regex(@"\[.*?\]");
        string text = "[something] [nothing interesting here] [boring.....]";
        int count = 0; 
        text = theRegex.Replace(text, delegate(Match thisMatch)
        {
            return "%" + (count++);
        }); // text is now '%0 %1 %2'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Regex.Replace`, it has a [handy overload that takes a callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx):

```
string s = "[something] [nothing interesting here] [boring.....]";
int counter = 0;
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\[[^\]]+\]", match => "%" + (counter++));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly since what you are describing has a procedural component. I think Perl might allow this though its qx operator (I think) but in general you need to loop over the string which should be pretty simple.

```
answer = ''
found  = 0
while str matches \[[^\[\]]\]:
    answer = answer + '%' + (found++) + ' '
```

Comment: Yeah, so you it wouldn't possible to make it with regex only ?

Comment: Regular expressions are used for matching / parsing. How would you replace anything using just regular expressions?

Comment: @Andy M: No, this is not possible with regular expressions only. You need some additional control strucutres.

Answer (score 1):

PHP and Perl both support a 'callback' replacement, allowing you to hook some code into generating the replacement. Here's how you might do it in PHP with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

```
class Placeholders{
   private $count;

   //constructor just sets up our placeholder counter 
   protected function __construct()
   {
      $this->count=0;
   }

   //this is the callback given to preg_replace_callback 
   protected function _doreplace($matches)
   {
      return '%'.$this->count++;
   }

   //this wraps it all up in one handy method - it instantiates
   //an instance of this class to track the replacements, and 
   //passes the instance along with the required method to preg_replace_callback       
   public static function replace($str)
   {
       $replacer=new Placeholders;
       return preg_replace_callback('/\[.*?\]/', array($replacer, '_doreplace'), $str);
   }
}


//here's how we use it
echo Placeholders::replace("woo [yay] it [works]");

//outputs: woo %0 it %1
```

You could do this with a global var and a regular function callback, but wrapping it up in class is a little neater.